# React route and empty page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Hi i am a new one in react. Trying routing and have some problems - empty main page. Dont understant whats the problem. React router dom version is "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1".

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

**App.js**

```
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './components/fonts/fonts.css';
import Cover from './components/cover/cover.jsx';
import FormRecal from './components/formRecal/form-recal.jsx';
import Header from './components/header/header.jsx';
import SecServises from './components/secServises/sec-servises.jsx';
import SecStory from './components/secStory/sec-story.jsx';
import SecPrice from './components/secPrice/sec-price.jsx';
import SecBot from './components/secBot/sec-bot.jsx';
import Footer from './components/footer/footer.jsx';
import './components/mediaScreen.css';
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <Cover/> 
        <FormRecal/>
        <Header/>
        <SecServises/>
        <SecStory/>
        <SecPrice/>
        <SecBot message1='I have been involved with this comapny for ages and just want to say this is a great work by designcoon.' name1='DJ Bravo - Frequent Travelera' message2='I have been involved with this comapny for ages and just.' name2='DJ Bravo - Frequent Travelera'/>
        <Footer/>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Cover/> } />
          </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What is the main page? `Cover` rendered on "/"?

Comment: Cover is a div that is used as a popup

Comment: So what is the main page and what is the issue?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please take the [tour], read [ask] and how to make a [mre] and [edit] your question to follow the guidelines.

Comment: Main page is index, and the issue is that that my code dont works, when i add <BrowserRouter> to App.js main page is whole empty.

Comment: I don't see any overt issues you the code you've shared, and it seems to render without issue in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-route-and-empty-page-66m7b). Are you certain you installed `react-router-dom` v6? Run `npm list react-router-dom` from your project directory. Maybe also try killing/restarting in code watchers/hot-reloaders.

Comment: thanks a lot, i found mistake->instal npm-route to a folder level above dir